# do 64-bit-only instruction set architectures exist?

Tags: 64-bit, cpu-architecture, 32-vs-64-bit

I read on Wikipedia that the x86_64 ISA, which is the 64-bit version of the x86 instruction set, is backward compatible with software written for the x86 architecture, not because of emulations but because it is hard-wired into the chip.

> Because the full x86 16-bit and 32-bit instruction sets remain implemented in hardware without any intervening emulation, existing x86 executables run with no compatibility or performance penalties, whereas existing applications that are recoded to take advantage of new features of the processor design may achieve performance improvements.

I really don't know much about CPU design. But some of the transistors inside there are used for just that backwards compatibility or not? Would a a CPU that supports a pure 64-bit ISA have more space left because the parts that are for the backwards compatibility are gone? Is there such a CPU? Is there an 64-bit ISA somewhere? Maybe planned?

Comment: You do understand that x86_64 (AMD64), is a x86 extension, that AMD developed.  Yes;  There is hardware that decodes what the extension is, but in the exact same way, as any x86 instruction is decoded.  There are many people that think, x86 architecture is to complicated, because of its ability to decode 8-bit and 16-bit instructions.  *Intel does not agree, consumers do not agree, otherwise Intel wouldn't continue to support those legacy instructions.*

Comment: Yes, I did read that.^^ I really think that such a processor that needs to support only a 64bit related ISA is better. And I think that Intel heads share that opinion, else wouldn't have done such an afford in creating the IA-64 ISA for the Itanium series.
>  In order to establish what was their first new ISA in 20 years and bring an entirely new product line to market, Intel made a massive investment in product definition, design, software development tools, OS, software industry partnerships, and marketing. To support this effort Intel created the largest design team in their history.

Comment: sorry. was out of space here is the source of the quote https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64#Itanium_9500_.28Poulson.29:_2012

Comment: If it was better then the market would have accepted it.  Intel clearly does not agree anymore, since they have not devloped any new IA-64 products, in years.  Futhermore Intel made a huge mistake not making x86 support a possible option IA-64, to easte the tranisition period, between x64 and IA-64

Comment: hmm. okeay you are right. the jump was to fast for the developers there was just still not enough x86 software alternatives out there. besides that: I want to know if there is any such processor out there with any such ISA.

Comment: Itanium is it.  ARM has 64-bit chips also but like x64, the ARM chips, support the 32-bit instructions also.

Comment: [ARMv8-A Architecture](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/armv8-architecture.php).  At the end of the day.  ISA architectures which do not support the previous architecture, are bound to fail.  [Cell](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/view_group.php?id=2649) architecture is one such example.  It was different enough from existing architectures, that developing was more difficult, it wasn't even similar to previous *IBM architectures* let alone x86 or ARM.

Comment: All x86-64 CPUs only run a dual x86/AMD64 front end/decoder. The actual execution unit is always 64 bit, just with varying operand sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 32-bit era has long gone. Almost all ISAs extensions to them in the '90s or '00s are 64-bit, many of them support dropping 32-bit support completely in the future. Pretty much **any *completely new* architectures that target high-performance computing are also pure 64-bit** because dual-32/64-bit support is mainly for backward compatibility of 32-bit programs and there are no 32-bit legacy binaries in such architectures to care about. Some examples:

- [ForwardCom](https://forwardcom.info/), a 64-bit [open-standard instruction set for high-performance microprocessors](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instructionset.pdf)
- [RISC-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC-V), the one that we hear the most in the recent years. Being new instruction set from the ground up, it can be 64-bit only or even 128-bit only

  There are zero old 32-bit code so there are no compatibility issues to worry about. The implementer is free to include support for both RV32 and RV64 but probably no one would bother to waste some effort and decoder space for that when no one needs to run old 32-bit code

  See [RV64 with RV32 instructions support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42225043/995714) and [RISC-V 32/64-bit compatibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55403515/995714)
- [OpenRISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenRISC), another new [open-standard instruction set](https://openrisc.io/architecture), similarly allows 64-bit only implementations without the need to support 32-bit code
- [Elbrus 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbrus_2000) is probably one of the latest in town, being pure **64-bit VLIW** like Itanium
- [MMIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX): also pure 64-bit

In fact **AArch64 was redesigned from scratch** like a new architecture and has nothing similar to the 32-bit ARM, so it's clear they see an extension to the old ISA won't be as sustainable, as what we've learned from x86. A new ISA allows ARM to drop the old ISA easily when everything has been mature enough. ARMv8 allows 64-bit only implementations, for example [Arm Cortex-A34](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arm_Cortex-A34) is a [64-bit Only Low-Power Core](https://www.cnx-software.com/2019/08/02/arm-cortex-a34-64-bit-only-low-power-core/), and [Qualcomm Falkor](https://www.cnx-software.com/2017/08/21/qualcomm-provides-details-about-64-bit-arm-falkor-cpu-cores-used-in-centriq-2400-server-on-chip/) is a [64-bit CPU purposely built for cloud workloads](https://www.qualcomm.com/news/onq/2017/08/introducing-qualcomm-falkor-cpu-core-purpose-built-cloud-workloads). If ARMv9 drops AArch32 then it's not unexpected at all

See also [Does it make sense for a clean-slate 64-bit instruction set to have 64-bit registers only? No need to care about backwards compat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73059014/995714)

In fact recently Intel has also proposed [the new simplified kind-of-64-bit-only x86S architecture](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/envisioning-future-simplified-architecture.html)

Comment: There are plenty of 32-bit-only RISC-V implementations for embedded uses.

Comment: @JohnDallman yes, but that's not backward compatible code like in the case of 32 → 64 transition, and RV64 implementations aren't required to have 32-bit support. RV64 users don't have old RV32 code to worry about

Answer (score 2):

The DEC Alpha was a genuinely 64-bit-only architecture, which was somewhat successful in the 1990s.

The early models of the Intel Itanium had a hardware x86 mode, intended to ease the transition. It was horribly slow, because it used the Itanium pipeline which was strictly in-order. The x86 processors available at the time (Pentium III, Pentium 4 and AMD Athlon) used out-of-order execution and ran x86 code much faster. Intel found it was possible to use dynamic binary translation to run x86 code on Itanium faster than the built-in hardware, and removed that hardware in later models, which thus became truly 64-bit only.

Some of the later ARMv8 and most ARMv9 Application-profile cores currently available are 64-bit only, and it seems that future application cores will all be like that. The ability to run ARM32 and Thumb code is being left out of new designs for that sector, to free chip space for improved ARM64 execution.

Comment: thank you. I didn't know the new ARM chips are 64bit.

Comment: @Junaga: Specifically, ARM v9 Cortex-A and Cortex-X cores. Cortex-M and Cortex-R cores are still 32-bit-capable at present.

Comment: there are already 64-bit only ARMv8 Cortex-A cores. You don't need to wait until ARMv9 for that

Comment: @phuclv: Thanks, added.